# Jest, how to ignore test coverage of specific folders?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

In my react project I have a root `./styles` folder which contains various style objects for styled-components. I do not want these files to show up in the coverage test.

I've tried to hide them like so, but when I run `npm run coverage` they still show up.

[image]

### package.json

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
  ],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/styles/",
    "./styles/"
  ],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/.next/",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/styles/",
    "./styles/"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js)$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.json5$": "json5-jest"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "json5",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
  ],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>/components/",
    "<rootDir>/pages/",
    "<rootDir>/shared/"
  ]
}
```

### babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", {"ssr": true, "displayName": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}],
        ["istanbul",{"exclude": ["styles/*.js"]}]
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel",
        "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", {"ssr": true, "displayName": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}]
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        ["next/babel", {"preset-env": { "modules": "commonjs" }}]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": true }],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        ["babel-plugin-sass-vars"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All I needed was this in package.json

```
"coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/styles/"
],
```

And removed it from `"testPathIgnorePatterns":` <- having it both here and in `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` caused my tests to run forever and styles still showed up.

I also removed this from the `.babelrc`:

```
["istanbul",{"exclude": ["styles/*.js"]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this to your config (package.json):

> modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["directoryNameToIgnore"]

or :

> modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["/dist/"]

2. and :

> coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/styles/"]

Comment: That didn't work, but just figured it out... posting now